# How would one dynamically load Javascript that has been parsed as PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am looking to dynamically load javascript that has been parsed as PHP so that I will be able to pass PHP variables to javascript, and then load this file into the primary PHP document. I have a document called myscript.js.php that includes the javascript and PHP. I attempted to load it into the primary document using jQuery's getScript like this:

```
$.getScript("myscript.js.php", function() {
                alert('loaded script.');
            });
```

This attempt failed - I am assuming because of the .php extension on the file. Is there anyway to dynamically load javascript that includes PHP? I have a few session variables that I am looking to pass through javascript that will be updated frequently, creating a need for the javascript to be reloaded.

Comment: what is myscript.js.php outputting?

Comment: It's outputting a set of javascript variables that are being set by PHP session variables.

Comment: Can we see it? The actual browser output without PHP.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
var cur_ad = "ad1";
var cur_ad_id = "new_ad4";
</script>`

Comment: I removed the <script> tags and the script seems to be loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your piece of code looks syntactically correct. Did you check the status of the ajax call?
you will have to set a header in the php page returned as,

```
header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8');
```

since otherwise jquery will throw an error since its expecting a script file to be returned and the header does not match it.

look at this.. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/#comment-104973932

Comment: This is probably the case, because it indeed does look correct otherwise.

Comment: I am still unable to return the script with this header at the top of "myscript.js.php"

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use AJAX to do this.

You can store the data the php script outputs into an array, implode the array in php, and echo out the imploded array.

Then you can get the string the ajax function returns and explode it back into an array and you will have the values you were trying to save to variables.

You can accomplish this with jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Not necessarily, in theory a dynamically generated javascript file on the server should work just fine using getScript.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically creating javascript like that probably isn't ideal. You're better off printing the raw data from php into a variable and your script can then use this data:

```
<?php

$config = array(
  // values
);

?>

<script>var config = <?php json_encode($config); ?>;</script>
<script src="myscript.js"></script> <!-- uses config data -->
```